# extract file/names from .torrent

Tags: c#

I have `.torrent` file and I want to extract all the file names from that file. I have tried searching but i am not having enough luck.

P.S:
I am writing a simple service which will watch a specific folder to upload my torrent files to my seedbox. Then another service will poll on my seedbox to download that downloaded files. There might be some torrents which i am not intrested to upload so my utility will upload specific torrents. I want to keep log of which torrent got uploaded so that i can fetch respective downloaded folder from my seedbox.

For reference, a torrent file may call Torrent_of_movie_2010.torrent file. But when the Torrent client would download, it will download it in a folder/or a file specified in .torrent file.

Comment: fwiw, .torrent files are bencoded, so you'll likely have to decode them before doing any processing of them.

Comment: [The BitTorrent Protocol Specification](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html)

Answer (score 0):

here is the simple Gist for you: 
https://gist.github.com/ttrider/bde3ebf5e7af6cd2b5ee

Comment: sorry dude, your gist doesn't work correctly. Some torrents - it trows exceptions on reading, some come back with really messed up and un-deserializable json.